# DrawerMenu W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461 en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

He creado un nuevo proyecto usando el asistente para implementar menú lateral `DrawerLayout`

al seleccionar del menú un ítem `onNavigationItemSelected` el debug me devuelve

> W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461

A que puede ser debido?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        Log.i(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected: ");
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

content_main.xlm

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.webserveis.app.testdrawable.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Gradle

```
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Comment: ¿A que parte del código te manda cuando clickeas ese error?

Comment: Al computar onNavigationItemSelected

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que yo entiendo, el problema está en uno de los iconos vectoriales (imagen en formato XML), durante el proceso de renderizado para pintar la imagen y/o armar la animación.
Habría que identificar la imagen que está generando el aviso, y analizar sus sentencias pathData.
Si interpreto bien el mensaje de error, habría que localizar cuando el enlace (punto origen->punto destino) es mayor que 4 (es cuando muestra el warning), y definir un punto intermedio.

Answer (score 0):

La solución no la sé 100% pero puedo asegurar que está en el tema de los iconos que usa la plantilla base de Android Studio, ha sido cambiarlos y ha desaparecido el error.

**drawables.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item name="ic_menu_home" type="drawable">@drawable/ic_home</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_list" type="drawable">@drawable/ic_view_list_black_24dp</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_map" type="drawable">@drawable/ic_map_black_24dp</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_settings" type="drawable">@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_about" type="drawable">@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp</item>
</resources>
```

**activity_main_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_home"
            android:title="Import" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_list"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_list"
            android:title="Gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_map"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_map"
            android:title="Slideshow" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_settings"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_about"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_about"
                android:title="Send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: son las imágenes que carga el layout,  podrías agregarlo?

Comment: Es exactamente lo que pienso, ya que verifiqué tu código con uno que tengo y está todo igual y el mío corre sin ningún problema .-.

Comment: Si a sido la forma de comparar proyectos y probar cambiar iconos, porque me estaba volviendo loco.